# Modificar desde DataGridView conectada a SQL en C#

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

Buen día,

me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación usando Windows Forms dentro de C#, es un registro de trabajadores en una tienda, los usuarios son ingresados desde un formulario dentro de la aplicación y son mostrados en el siguiente modulo en un DataGridView el cual esta conectado a una base de datos SQL server.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El DataGridView al abrir el modulo de consulta aparece como bloqueado hasta que presionamos el botón editar, ahí es cuando los registros pueden ser actualizados, para guardar los cambios se presiona el botón "guardar" pero tengo dos problemas:

1. Solamente puedo editar el primer registro, si intento editar el segundo no hace lo cambios.
2. Al momento de editar el primer registro, cambia todos los registros y los deja guardados como el primero.

Anexo el código que estoy utilizando para el botón guardar:

```
 private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand agregar = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Usuarios SET Nombre = @nombre, Apellido = @apellido, Fecha_Nacimiento = @fecha , Telefono = @telefono ", cadena);


            try
            {

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Nombre"].Value));
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apellido", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Apellido"].Value));
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Fecha Nacimiento"].Value));
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Telefono"].Value));
                    agregar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Usuario Registro Exitoso");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            }


        }
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme con este problema que tengo se los agradecería mucho, saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: No soy partidario de hacer consultas SQL dentro del CodeBehind, mi recomendación es que crees un SP y lo consumas. Dejando de lado esto, el problema que tienes es que no estas filtrando el registro al cual se debe modificar debes agregar un WHERE a tu consulta SQL. Recuerda que los registros siempre, pero siempre deben tener un ID es una buena practica así no lo llegases a utilizar nunca.

Answer (score 1):

Tu inconveniente esta aqui

```
SqlCommand agregar = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Usuarios SET Nombre = @nombre, Apellido = @apellido, Fecha_Nacimiento = @fecha , Telefono = @telefono ", cadena);
```

cuando estas realizando la actualizacion no le esta indicando a que usuario el va a actualizar por eso te los actualiza todos

te recomendaria que obtuvieras el codigo de usuario y lo pongas como condicion, te muestro como

```
SqlCommand agregar = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Usuarios SET Nombre = @nombre, Apellido = @apellido, Fecha_Nacimiento = @fecha , Telefono = @telefono where codusuario = @codigo ", cadena);
```

asi podras modificar el registro que deseas.

Comment: Hola Frankestainero, ¿entonces me recomiendas modificar la base de datos y agregar una clave para cada usuario?. Saludos

Comment: Efectivamente eso es lo que tienes que hacer porque el código del usuario es que le va a decir que registro el debe actualizar, porque si no lo haces asi siempre te va a actulizar todos los registro

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste Frankenstainero, tengo la siguiente duda, si dejo el ID como autoincrementable, como puedo hacer para declararlo pero que este no sea tomado para modificar: 
`SqlCommand actualizar = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Usuarios SET  id_usuario = @codigo, Nombre = @nombre, Apellido = @apellido, Fecha_Nacimiento = @fecha , Telefono = @telefono where id_usuario = @codigo  ", cadena);`

lo declaro asi:
`actualizar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["ID"].Value));`

¿o quito mejor el autoincrementado?

Comment: @EzequieLopez los muestras en el datagridview y obtienes el valor como hacer con los demas valores

Comment: Asi esta bien como lo tienes no quites el auto incrementador

Comment: Lo intente pero no me actualiza, ni me marca error.

Comment: Muestrame el error que te esta indicando

Comment: El nombre de la variable @codigo ya se ha declarado. Los nombres de variables deben ser únicos en cada lote de consultas o procedimiento almacenado. El Problema creo es porque como es un ciclo se vuelven a declarar. y como el foreach analiza columna por columna, pienso yo que es por eso.

Comment: El problema es que en el set estas colocando id_usuario = @codigo no debes colocarlo hay solo en el where